# How to check whether all number elements in an array are even numbers with recursion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, ecmascript-6

I'm currently learning as much as I can about recursion but I'm really stuck on how to use it to check whether all the number elements in an array are even numbers. With ES6, I can use "every" to achieve the desire outcome as follow:

```
const isEven = (arr) => arr.every((item) => item % 2 === 0);
console.log(isEven([2,4,6,8])); // true
console.log(isEven([2,4,6,9])); // false
```

The following is my attempt as recursion:

```
const isEven = (arr) => (arr.length === 0) ? true : isEven(arr.slice(1)) % 2 === 0;
console.log(isEven([2,4,6,8])); // true
console.log(isEven([2,4,6,9])); // true
```

As you can see, the result is incorrect for the 2nd example and I have a feeling that I'm not on the right path either. Can someone kindly show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just do it the ES6 way. This is a terrible misapplication of recursion. If you're learning recursion for pedagogical reasons, it's important to pick problems that it's actually useful for, like traversing a binary tree, which breaks the problem down by a nonlinear factor. If you really have to do this, use an index into the array rather than slice. This algorithm is unnecessarily O(n*n) even when you fix the bug.

Comment: @ggorlen: I respectfully disagree.  A head-tail list is an equally valid recursive structure and simpler for newcomers than a tree.  While JS doesn't natively supply lists, dense arrays provide  a reasonable facsimile of them, using `[0]` and `.slice(1)`, or better yet if those are reified as `head` and `tail` or `first` and `rest`  (Let's not go all the way to `car` and `cdr`, please!)   Yes, the performance will be abysmal, but that's not the point for a learning exercise.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yep, we've disagreed in the past on this. The problem is that newcomers don't really realize that you'd _never_ do this sort of thing in production JS. They're taught recursion as if it's somehow the way people code business apps in JS. It's not. `arr.every` is so much more idiomatic. It's worse than a performance issue: your list will blow the stack if it's more than a few thousand measly elements. Why teach JS like it's Haskell? Teach Haskell paradigms with Haskell, teach JS paradims with JS. Otherwise people just get uber-confused, as I see daily in the [tag:recursion] tag.

Comment: To leave a post up like this _without_ a comment about the accidental quadratic complexity and security hole that recursion opens is a disservice for future visitors and the SO community that might attempt to use this sort of fundamentally broken code in production, in addition to failing to guide the student to think critically about the tasks they're being given. Please pardon me in advance because I leave such a comment whenever I see it!

Comment: @ggorlen: I'll try to remember not to respond. ;-)  Because I have almost the exact opposite idea.  Use the simplest code that works, and optimize for performance only when it shows itself to be a problem.  But I also use recursion a great deal for my day-to-day business coding, so maybe I'm just an oddball.  Maybe I take that back; I might well still respond, because I think people do need to hear that there is debate on this topic.

Comment: Great! See you in the "pit". _use the simplest code that works_ -- I agree: `arr.every((item) => item % 2 === 0);`!!

Comment: @ggorlen: :-) "... except use the tools required by the pedagogical approach when applicable."  There is of course absolutely no reason to write this function recursively.  And if someone does it as a learning exercise, they should be warned that it might knock them down, launch the missiles or steal their girlfriends.  But they should also learn *how* to do it.  BTW, what is the "security hole" you mentioned?

Comment: The security hole is an uncaught crash bringing the application down. I'd be fine if students prefaced these posts with "I realize this is a terrible way to do it, but my professor is making me do it this way". But that's almost never the case. I'm frustrated that the CS education system is forcing students to hammer nails with screwdrivers left and right, without explaining the caveats. Recursion is actually super useful, so if they could simply pick problems where it's simpler than any alternative, students would appreciate the tool. I don't believe in contrived examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that `isEven` returns a `boolean` but you try to use the result as if it is a number. So, it turns out that the return result is solely based on the number of elements, as each time it gets flipped:

```js
console.log("true % 2 === 0 :", true % 2 === 0);
console.log("false % 2 === 0:", false % 2 === 0);

const isEven = (arr) => (arr.length === 0) ? true : isEven(arr.slice(1)) % 2 === 0;
console.log(isEven([]));     // true
console.log(isEven([1]));    // false
console.log(isEven([1, 1])); // true
```

If we write out your function fully instead as a single conditional operator, we can see what is happening better by adding some logging:

```js
const isEven = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    console.log("base case - finish recursion. result: true");
    return true;
  }
  const recursionValue = isEven(arr.slice(1));
  const result = recursionValue % 2 === 0;
  console.log(`After recursion: 
  recursionValue: ${recursionValue} 
  result        : ${result}`);
  return result;
}

console.log(isEven([2,4,6,9])); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Or to illustrate this differently, this is how the recursion will be resolved:

```
isEven([2,4,6,9])
| --> | isEven([4,6,9]) % 2 === 0
|     | --> | isEven([6,9]) % 2 === 0
|     |     | --> | isEven([9]) % 2 === 0
|     |     |     | --> isEven([]) % 2 === 0
|     |     |     |   | --> arr.length === 0 --> true
|     |     |     |   | true % 2 === 0 --> false
|     |     |     | false % 2 === 0  --> true
|     |     | true % 2 === 0 --> false
|     | false % 2 === 0 --> true
| true
```

---

To achieve what you want, you need to be checking the first element each time, not the result of `isEven`.

- If the array is empty, then the whole array must have been even. This is the base case. The recursion ends and the result is `true`
- If the first element is odd, then not all of the array is even. This is a terminal condition. End the recursion and return `false` - that means that the base case will not be reached.
- If there *are* items in the array and the first item is even, just recurse by using the rest of the array checking the above two conditions each time.

This ensures that you either get `true` if the second condition is never reached, or `false` if it ever is.

```js
const isEven = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) // empty - base case
    return true;
  if (arr[0] % 2 === 1) // odd - stop and return false
    return false;
    
  return isEven(arr.slice(1)); // recursion
}

console.log(isEven([2,4,6,8])); // true
console.log(isEven([2,4,6,9])); // false
```

Comment: VLAZ--> I wanna thank you for your thorough explantion on how things work. This really helps me learn and improve. Your use case of the 1st element to check for odd number on each recursive call is very clever. Orignally, I wanted to write a function to check whether all the elements in an array is either [ even | odd ]. By you sharing your knowledge with me, I was able to achieve that with your logic :) 
--> const check = (arr) => (!arr.length) ? 'even' : (arr[0] % 2 === 1) ? 'odd' : check(arr.slice(1));

Comment: @noirsociety I wouldn't return a string literal `'even'` or `'odd`'. Return a logical boolean true/false type. The caller can then use this type idiomatically and dynamically to format a string for pretty output, _if_ desired, for example: `console.log(isEven(whatever) ? "even" : "odd")`. With a string approach, callers can't rely on the normal boolean code `if (isEven(whatever)) {}` because all strings are truthy, even if their contents linguistically indicate falseness.

Comment: @VLAZ That is such a great point. Thanks for teaching me the all the best practice for this example 

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `isEven(arr.slice(1)) % 2 === 0` part. The `isEven` function is supposed to return a boolean, for which it doesn't make sense to to take the modulo.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
isEven = arr => arr.length === 0 ? true : arr[0] % 2 === 0 && isEven(arr.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The premise should be:

*The array is even if the first element is even and the rest of the array (which is also an array) is also even*

So basically:

```
const isEven = (arr) => (arr.length === 0) ? true : arr[0] % 2 === 0 && isEven(arr.slice(1));
```

Which can be rewritten a little bit with destructuring to exemplify it better.

```
const isEven = ([first, ...rest]) =>
    (first % 2 === 0) &&
    (rest.length ? isEven(rest) : true);
```

Comment: "*The array is even if the first element is even and the rest of the array (which is also an array) is also even*" this would mean that an empty array is not even. Which is is different to `[].every(x => x % 2 === 0)` - that code returns `true`. OP uses `.every()` as a comparison and an empty array has fulfilled the condition.

Comment: Well that condition can be added, e.g. "The array is even if it's empty or..." for completion.

Comment: The destructuring example does not match that description though..

Comment: The destructuring example can handle that with `const isEven = ([first, ...rest]) => first == undefined || (first % 2 == 0 && isEven (rest))`, so long as `undefined` is not an allowed input, and can be handled with a local Symbol if needed: `const None = Symbol(); const isEven = ([first = None, ...rest]) => first == None || (first % 2 == 0 && isEven (rest))`.  (Yes I know that the parentheses are not necessary, but I think they're cleaner.)

Comment: And if you never saw [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) before, you can read about them here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-symbols-24650a163038